# The GUI is not loading after installing xubuntu-desktop package for Ubuntu

Tags: boot-issues, ubuntu, gui

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I have followed the instructions outlined here:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#1-overview.

Everything works fine until I reach the steps for installing a GUI. I chose to use xubuntu-desktop. Once everything has finished installing, I type the command `sudo reboot`. The system reboots into the command line interface and then reaches the login prompt on the command line and quickly disappears only to be replaced by a black screen.

I've tried blindly typing out the user name and password just in case the command line is not visible but nothing happens. It's just a black screen.

Can anyone help me figure out how to make this work? I've followed the steps in the tutorial closely twice now. I've searched online for fixes and I'm only finding how-to's for how to install Ubuntu or how to install GUIs.

Comment: I think you would be better off asking on the Ubuntu forums.

Comment: Hello joan, thank you for your comment.